# EventTrigger to attached event

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I'm trying to use a Expression Blend EventTrigger (`System.Windows.Interactivity` namespace) to an attached event (namely `DragDrop.DragEnter/DragLeave` from the Silverlight Toolkit). Is this possible without writing my own custom trigger? The `EventName` property of the `EventTrigger` seems to be a simple String, so I'm not sure what the syntax is for attached events if even possible...

Example:

```
<sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid Name="Root" AllowDrop="True">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="[Silverlight Toolkit DragEnter]">
         <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="DragOver" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="[Silverlight Toolkit DragLeave]">
         <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="NoDragOver" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In Expression Blend 4 in the propeties for the GoToStateAction, you can select the event name in the Trigger Section.  That creates this Xaml:

```
<sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,153,0,227" Width="100">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragEnter">
        <ei:GoToStateAction/>
           </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid>
```

Comment: The question was about the Drag-Events from the Silverlight Toolkit (attached events), not the normal Silverlight events for drag and drop!